# Is data leakage in time series due to both I's of the IID principe or only one?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, data-leakage

I am sure that the Independent part of the IID principle gives you data leakage because of the correlation. But the identical part I am not so sure. Identical in time series means that your data is stationary (and not changing in distribution over time). If your data thus is not identical you would for example have a rising average, which you could detrend, but is this then also data leakage if you would not detrend this rising average?